Error: The amm account owner is not match with this program" error
Anyone can help, I am getting Program logged: "Error: The amm account owner is not match with this program" error,. Program returned error: "custom program error: 0x1b" I created token and LP via https://tools.smithii.io/liquidity-pool/solana and all worked fine, however Opebbook market was created with cheapest option so I decided to make another one, so I created it but it didnt allow me to create another LP. Maybe that's the problem but cant do anything with it, so users cant trade too. Maybe something else was done by mistake, I was pressing. revoke free authority however it supposed to be fine.
